# How to get SSL Certificate from Azure Webrole file?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles

I have some certificates in my WebRole file. I need to save those certificates and add to other project. so i am unable to save those certificates from Visual Studio. can any one of you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure project file only stores the thumbprint information for the certificate. You can see this information in the cscfg file under section `Certificates`. This implies you can copy these entries into any Azure config file.

This does not mean that the certificate would be available to the deployment. Depending upon whether you are uploading certificate into a service (for SSL configuration) or uploading as a Management certificate, you need a pfx or CER file for it. For certificates uploaded to your service you need certificate in pfx format with embedded private key.

See this [msdn link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/) for installing a SSL certificate for a Service.

Comment: yes.. we need .pfx files with embedded private key for azure services. i am able to save some certificates in both formats (.pfx & .cer), but i am unable to save some of certificate in .pfx format(with private key). So, how can i get those certificates?

Comment: You cannot. When you install certificate on your system, it ask whether to make the private key exportable. If that is not selected you do not get export private key option. You cannot hence get it from the system, if marked as non exportable. You need the certificate which was originally acquired or get it from a machine where it was installed with export option.